# Counting duplicate ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    CustomerID VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE [Transaction]
(
    TransactionID VARCHAR,
    CustomerID VARCHAR REFERENCES Customer.CustomerID
)

INSERT INTO Customer VALUES ('CO1')
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES ('C02')
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES ('C03')

INSERT INTO [Transaction] VALUES ('T01', 'C01')
INSERT INTO [Transaction] VALUES ('T02', 'C01')
INSERT INTO [Transaction] VALUES ('T03', 'C01')
INSERT INTO [Transaction] VALUES ('T04', 'C02')
INSERT INTO [Transaction] VALUES ('T05', 'C02')
INSERT INTO [Transaction] VALUES ('T06', 'C03')
```

I want to select `CustomerID, COUNT(TransactionID)` where the customer has done more than one transactions, so it should be C01 and C02 that appear.

Here's what I've come up with

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID, [Total Transaction] = COUNT(TransactionID)
FROM
    Customer a
JOIN 
    [Transaction] b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
WHERE 
    (SELECT COUNT(TransactionID) 
     FROM [Transaction] a 
     JOIN Customer b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID) > 1
GROUP BY 
    CustomerName
```

The problem is C03 keeps appearing so there must be some error on my subquery I don't know about

Comment: @DaleK I'm really sorry. I was about to accept but it read something along "you can accept after 10 mins" or something and I guess I forgot about it. Will remember next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a basic `GROUP BY` query here:

```sql
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS num_transactions
FROM [Transaction]
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Side note: `TRANSACTION` is a reserved SQL Server keyword, and therefore you should avoid naming your database objects using it.  So, consider changing to some other name.

Comment: it worked very well, thank you for the help!